# Is there a way to turn off xemacs auto backup files in a specific directory only?

Tags: xemacs

XEmacs always creates a file named foo.txt~ when you edit foo.txt. This can be really useful but not really when you are using source control on your files.

I know you can use (setq make-backup-files nil) to turn it off altogether but was wondering if there was a way to turn it off only in particular directories.

Comment: I put all backup files under a "unified" location and keep them out of work tree entirely e.g. see http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BackupDirectory if you really want to get fancy, perhaps start at http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BackupEachSave Happy emacs'ing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version control package will detect if you're in a CVS, RCS, or SCCS repository and disable backups. If you're using another VC backend like hg, git, or svn, you may need to install additional packages to enable emacs to detect their repositories.